# How can I print byte type elements on the screen in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I used the printf function. As far as I know just doubleword type of variables/registers can be pushed. So at first I converted the bites to doublewords, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
bits 32 
global start
extern exit, printf 
import exit msvcrt.dll
import printf msvcrt.dll

segment data use32 class=data
 D db 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', '2', '%', 'x'
 len EQU $-D
```

I would like to print out what **D** contains. I tried in two ways:

1.

```
segment code use32 class=code
    start:
        mov ecx, len
        mov esi, 0
        show_on_screen:
            mov al,[D+esi]
            mov ah, 0
            mov dx,0
            push dx
            push ax
            pop eax
            push dword eax
            call [printf]
            add esp, 4
            inc esi
        loop show_on_screen
        push    dword 0      
        call    [exit]
```

2. I added in data segment a variable

```
char db 'x', 0
```

```
segment code use32 class=code
    start:
    mov ecx, len
    mov esi,0
    show_characters:
     mov al,[D+esi]
     mov [char], al
     push dword char
     call [printf]
     add esp,4
     inc esi
    loop show_characters
    push    dword 0      
    call    [exit] 
​
```

Comment: So what was the result of your attempts?

Comment: In the first case nothing appeared on the screen, in the second this: aAbB2xx╣╛èå►@ó►@h►@ §D0@â─♦FΓΣj §@0@40(0@0msvcrt.dllL0T0Év░L    vexitprintf ↕♀0◄0▬0∟0*0

Comment: Do you know how printf works? It requires a format string as its first argument. Your second attempt almost works except that `%` is special so you need to escape that (or better, use a `%c` format string) and also `printf` is allowed to destroy `ecx` hence you need to save and restore your counter.

Comment: Your second case implies you kept looping beyond the end of the char array. So check your loop count logic.

Comment: Is this NASM?  It's not MASM but could maybe be FASM, IDK.  For 32-bit x86 for Windows, clearly.

Comment: Also obviously if you want to print characters you might be interested in `putchar` instead of `printf`. And if you want to print your whole string at once, you can use `printf("%.*s\n", len, D)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I saved and restored the initial value of ecx and it is working. Also, printing the whole string so easily amazed me. Thank you, really :)

Comment: And yes, it is NASM